# Can sprinklr use Microsoft qna maker and LUIS by simple configuration?

Tags: azure-qna-maker, azure-language-understanding, sprinklr

We want to use sprinklr platform to use qna and LUIS. How can it be integrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these docs for LUIS and QnA integration

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/choose-natural-language-processing-service
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs